# how to install vendor package from laravel package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

So i'am in **Laravel 5.4** and i've my custom package `packages/dev/mypackage`.

And i want to install `soundasleep/html2text` into my package, so i add this to my `packages/dev/mypackage/composer.json` :

```
{
  "require": {
    "soundasleep/html2text": "~0.5"
  }
}
```

then composer update , but when i tried to call `Html2Text\Html2Text` i got always class `Html2Text\Html2Text` not found.

So please if someone has any idea i'll be very appreciative.

Comment: go to your config folder and find app.php add class name with full path in 'provider' array...

Comment: i don't have any app.php in my package

Comment: Why don't you have config/app.php in your laravel app?

Comment: Did you check that the package was correctly installed ? look if the **/vendor** directory contains a directory **soundasleep/html2text**. @molagbal This package isn't a laravel package, it hasn't a provider.

Answer (score 0):

first use `Html2Text\Html2Text` then call html2text

Comment: i already tried Html2Text\Html2Text, the same problem class not found